# How to print "Y" if it has a certain value in a column

Tags: sql

I have a **TABLE A**.

And I have column **AA** and **BB** in the table.

And if I want to print "Y" for a new column if column **AA** has a data = '1',

How should I write the query?

For instance,

```
If AA has a column look like this,

 AA
====
 3

 3

 1

 4
```

Because it has a data =1, I want to print Y.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you targetting?

Comment: What do you want it to print if `AA` isn't one? Nothing? `N`?

Comment: Do you want to PRINT 'Y' as a message, or do you want to SELECT 'Y' as a column in a resultset?

Comment: I want to print Y as a data in a new column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query:

```
select case 
       when aa = 1 
       then 'Y' 
       else null
       end
from   a
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can tackle this problem by using case keyword. Try to lookup.

```
SELECT Case when AA=1 then 'Y' else 'somehthin' End
    From...
    Where...
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified the flavour of SQL you're using so I'll assume T-SQL

Try using the CASE WHEN THEN statement

e.g.

```
SELECT 
AA, 
CASE AA 
  WHEN 1 THEN 'Y'
END AS Filter
FROM 
A;
```

See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) for further information on how to use the CASE statement in Transact-SQL

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
[AA],
'Result' =
CASE WHEN [AA] = 1
THEN 'Y'
ELSE 'N'
END
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is Microsoft SQL Server, and you wish to print 'Y' as a message, you could do:

```
if exists (select * from a where aa='1')
print 'Y'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #t (AA int)

insert into #t values(3),(3),(1),(4)

select AA,case when AA=1 then 'Y' end as BB from #t
```

<kbd>[Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fe6d5/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
Select aa,case aa when 1 then 'Y' else '' end as newColumn
From TableA
```